# How to use intl DateFormat to convert string "1030" to "10:30am"

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-intl

I am dealing with time strings such as "1030" or "0230"

I am trying:

```
var time = "1030";
DateFormat.jm().format(DateFormat("hhmm").parse(time));
```

However that throws the following error:

```
Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Trying to read mm from 1030 at position 4
```

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: Nvm, I guess I have to substring the time into "hour:min" and use "hh:mm", then it works. So, convert the time "1030" to "10:30", and then use "hh:mm"..

Comment: https://github.com/dart-lang/intl/issues/210

Comment: Thanks. I figured it out insted by, just substring the parts split by colon, and use hh:mm.

Answer (score 4):

use

> HH:mm

```
var time = "10:30";
DateFormat.jm().format(DateFormat("HH:mm").parse(time));
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I end up doing, however I have to substring. I am using google places api fwiw, and place in the colon in between between